# Is right connect a 3.3 V power supply to energize the VNH2SP30 monster motor shield?

Tags: motor-controller

I bought a VNH2SP30 monster motor shield. I have a question about the right way to energize this shield because, as the picture shows, the monster motor shield has +3.3v, 5v, Vin and gnd power supply inputs.

Is it possible to supply the VNH2SP30 with 3.3v or 5v?

[image]

[image]

---

Here is the schematic of Monster Motor Shield :

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like the shield needs at least 5.5VDC. The `+5V` and `+3.3V` that you are seeing on the silkscreen are voltage outputs for your other shield (e.g. Arduino).

Comment: I was suspicious when I saw "shield" possibly used out of correct context.  No, arduinees don't get to re-define long-standing EE terms.  Then I saw a cartoon where it looks like a schematic should be.  -1 and closing.  I'm done here.

Comment: The shield is the name that Sparkfun used to call the arduino circuits, but those circuits are avalaible for other MCUs development boards.

Answer (score 0):

The 3.3V pin is not connected to anything. The board can only be powered by 5V. The pin is only present for extending the labeling from the arduino it is designed to sit on top of.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I have a question about the right way to energize this shield ...

and

> Is it possible to supply the VNH2SP30 with 3.3v or 5v?

You have two things mixed here, power supply for the shield itself and power supply for VNH2SP30 motor driver (which also becomes power for your motors).

The shield draws power from 5+ Arduino pin, and all the pins not drawn with wires on your picture are actually not connected to anything. The markings next to them are FYI only.

The VNH2SP30 datasheet specifies operating range 5.5-16V, which is above what you can get from Arduino. And even if it wasn't above, you can't draw enough power for motors from that 5V, unless they are something like tiny pager motors.